# cycling through a list when an event occurs and displaying it on the screen

Tags: python, events, button, tkinter, sudoku

I am creating a Sudoku game, and i have generated a series of buttons creating a 9x9 grid. Every time a button is clicked, i would like it to cycle through a list of numbers 1-9 (so if i want the button to read 6, the button needs to be clicked 6 times). I have managed to achieve this, however when i bring it onto my main code which includes the grid, it doesnt work.

```
#Create a 9x9 (rows x columns) grid of buttons inside the frame
for row_index in range(9):
    for col_index in range(9):
        if (row_index in {0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8} and col_index in {3, 4, 5}) or \
                (row_index in {3, 4, 5} and col_index in {0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8}): #Colours a group of 3x3 buttons together to differentiate the board better.
            colour = 'gray85'
        else:
            colour = 'snow'
        x = random.randint(1,9)
        btn = Button(frame, width = 12, height = 6, bg=colour) #create a button inside frame 
        btn.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky=N+S+E+W)

def LeftClick(event, btn):
    global position
    btn.config(text=list1[position])
    position=position+1
    if position == len(list1):
        position=0

btn.bind("<Button-1>", LeftClick)
```

Any idea why this isn't working? Currently nothing happens when i click the button.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean - I have included my sample code.

Comment: Copy / paste your sample does it do anything?

Comment: No the sample doesn't do anything - i stated that. When the button is clicked it remains blank. Unfortunately i cant show the actual outcome as i dont have gyazo or anything like this and print screen cannot be printed here. Sorry

Comment: Sorry, if you haven't time to read [mcve], I haven't time to help.

Comment: @JamesAnderson The sample **does** something, it raises an exception.

Comment: I have provided a minimal complete and verifiable example...

Comment: @JamesAnderson No, you haven't. The code above is not even Minimal in the sense that it has only the parts needed to reproduce the issue you're having. It has some parts, and some redundant parts. Now non-redundant parts are not enough to reproduce the problem, so it's not Complete or Verifiable. It is basically _some code_.

Comment: Ah - i tried to direct the code simply to the area in which the problem lies. Sorry if it wasnt enough to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure `LeftClick()` is called by adding a `print('click')` test message to it. Also you need to bind the function to the button. Add this within your `for` loop:

```
btn.bind("<Button-1>", LeftClick)
```

The `LeftClick()` function needs to be updated as follows:

```
def LeftClick(event):
    next_value = " 123456789 "

    try:
        current_value = next_value[next_value.index(str(int(event.widget['text']))) + 1]
    except ValueError:
        current_value = "1"

    event.widget.config(text=current_value)
```

This reads the current text in the button and picks the next value to use from `next_value`. This includes a space to allow you to unselect a cell. So to start with it would fail and be given a starting value of `1`. The next click it would read the `1`, convert it to an integer and find the index of the value in `next_value`. It then picks the value at the next index.

---

To code the `New Game` button you would need to change the text on each button one at a time, currently you only do the last created button. To do this you need to keep a reference to all of the buttons you create. Currently the code overwrites each button variable with the next. At the top of the code add an empty buttons list:

```
buttons = []
```

Next inside your `for` loop under the bind:

```
buttons.append(btn)
```

Then your `Clear()` function can be as follows:

```
def Clear(): 
    for btn in buttons:
        btn.config(text=" ")
```

Comment: Ive implemented this and tried it out, however it still doesnt display any numbers on my button grid.

Comment: Is the function being called? Add a `print()` statement to it to test it.

Comment: It should be being called - i have synced button clicks with the function

Comment: btn.bind("<Button-1>", LeftClick)
I have this on my code

Comment: Correction - i added print to the function and nothing gets outputted. Any ideas why??

Comment: How do you assign `LeftClick()` as the function to be called?

Comment: Well i bind leftclick to the left click of a mouse button - the event. Therefore whenever i left click on the button it should call the function

Comment: You would need something like `btn.bind('<Button-1>', LeftClick)`, but the code you have posted does not show how this is done.

Comment: I have got this - i will edit the post to show this aswell.

Comment: Try moving the `bind()` call to within your `for` loop after where you assign `btn`.

Comment: You're currently only binding to the last instance of btn, rather than for every button you create inside the loop. I presume the last button on your grid works but the others don't?

Comment: I have moved it to within the for loop and i get the following error message when i click on any button        TypeError: LeftClick() missing 1 required positional argument: 'btn'

Comment: Any ways to fix this?

Comment: Callbacks only take one parameter. The `event` contains the attribute of the widget which you can use.

Comment: Okay thanks - i removed btn from the paramters, and when i run and click a button, test gets printed. So the function is being called., however nothing gets displayed on the actual button yet

Comment: Are you using `event.widget.config(text=next(list1))` ?

Comment: im using btn.config(text=next(list1))

Comment: However still the same problem - function gets called but no display on the button

Comment: You could post a link to your full code using a service like [0bin](https://0bin.net/)

Comment: Theres the code. Some bits of the code are irrelevant and are just there for "test purposes"

Comment: One more adjustment - I added in this function which is meant to reset the whole board. The code goes as follows "                                                               def Clear():
    btn.config(text=" ") "                                                                             When "New Game" is clicked on the menu bar, this function gets called. However it does not change the text on the buttons - any reason why?

Comment: You need to clear each button individually. To do this you need to keep a list of the buttons you create. I have updated the answer to show you how.